# Incorrect paths getting shown while executing "hadoop version" from cygwin command prompt

Tags: windows, hadoop, cygwin

I have installed Hadoop 1.x and Cygwin on my Windows 7 machine and have set home path and bin path in .bashrc as follows.

## .bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/java/jdk1.7
export HADOOP_HOME=/cygdrive/c/apache/hadoop
export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin/:$PATH
```

While executing command "hadoop version" at the command prompt I see error messages related to paths as shown below. Please guide as which paths are not set correctly. I have installed both Hadoop and Java in C:/apache/hadoop and C:/Java/jdk1.7 respectively.

## Cygwin command prompt

```
$ hadoop version
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

/cygdrive/c/apache/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 350: /cygdrive/c/java/jdk1.7/bin/bin/java: No such file or directory
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\apache\hadoop\/build/native
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/apache/hadoop/build/native
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
/cygdrive/c/apache/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 434: /cygdrive/c/java/jdk1.7/bin/bin/java: No such file or directory
/cygdrive/c/apache/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 434: exec: /cygdrive/c/java/jdk1.7/bin/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Hadoop needs Java version to run, but according to the error message '/cygdrive/c/java/jdk1.7/bin/bin/java' isn't not a correct path. So I suggest that you verify that path

Comment: As you can see in my bash.rc I have set the correct path of Java. I am not able to figure out what's wrong. When I run java -version command in cygwin it works and shows the correct version of java without any issues.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem after changing the Java home path in hadoop-env.sh from /cygdrive/c/java/jdk1.7/bin to /cygdrive/c/java/jdk1.7

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem after changing the Java home path in hadoop-env.sh from `/cygdrive/c/java/jdk1.7/bin`to`/cygdrive/c/java/jdk1.7`